# Possible to change Outlook SMIME icon from RED to Blue?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, icons, smime, exchange-2013

Every SMIME clear signed message has a red icon located near the Urgent exclamation point as shown below.

This is often confused with high priority, and sends the wrong subtle message.  IMHO a red SMIME icon should only appear for improperly signed messages, not validly signed ones.

What Icon DLL can I edit, or registry setting can I use to change this?

**Outlook 2013 expanded view**

[image]

---

**Default view**

[image]

---

.

Comment: I am looking at an encrypted email in my inbox.  I see a blue lock over an envelope or are you talking about the 'award icon` over the same envelope indicating that it was signed by a certificate?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I'm talking about the award icon.  The feedback I'm getting is that it's getting confused with high priority messages... and confuses people when an invalid certificate is present

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that fact because those emails are not encrypted they are just digitally signed by the sender.  I am looking into it what your options are.  So these users are looking the certificate icon over the envelope and thinking its high importance instead of the explanation mark all the way to the right near the category and flag columns?

Comment: @Ramhound Added an image, and specified Clearsigned.

Comment: This is odd.  I can't recreate your layout.  You might look into just hiding the icon to avoid the confusion.  The invalid signature notice will be displayed regardless.  What column is showing that icon?

Comment: @Ramhound is the preview pane to the right?  try squeezing it to the left... windows will change the layout.  I added another view that is similar

Answer (score 0):

No way, sorry. This icon is stored in Outlook resource files as a simple bitmap image. You can't change this. Theoretically you can edit msores.dll resources but this will break digital signature and office can replace this dll on any update.